# pristine svn-base file missing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to `svn update` my SVN working copy with TortoiseSVN but the update fails, asking to perform the clean up first.

However, the `svn cleanup` fails too stating that a `\.svn\pristine\20\20long-namecbf.svn-base file cannot be found`.

I've already tried to release the lock but this does not work either.

**Any idea how should I proceed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SmartSVN](http://www.smartsvn.com/) to restore lost pristine file.

Download and install it. It's not free but 30 days free trial should be enough to repair your repository. 

Open your working copy in **SmartSVN**. To repair, select ***Modify*** > ***Validate Admin Area...***

Enjoy!

Comment: Please add how, I have seen a few references to SmartSVN, but all fail to explain how.

Comment: Thank you duccom, this makes much more sense.

Answer (score 45):

This problem:

> cannot find the file .svn\pristine\24\24fd530d4bd82341fb514ab912c9e10adbc4ad89.svn-base

I copied a svn-base from other file and renamed this with 24fd530d4bd82341fb514ab912c9e10adbc4ad89.svn-base. And perform a clean up operation. After that I met another file missing. Using the same way, and at last I fixed this problem.

From a Windows command line with SilkSVN installed:

```
cd project directory
svn status
```

This will generate an error. Select and copy the directory and filename text then paste:

```
echo > .svn\pristine\<paste>
```

For example:

```
echo > 24\24fd530d4bd82341fb514ab912c9e10adbc4ad89.svn-base
```

With this knowledge in hand, it would be reasonably trivial to write a batch file that can fix these problems automatically for everyone. The svn command will generate an %ERRORLEVEL% value that can be checked for failure.

Comment: This led me to an even simpler solution: just create an empty file with the given filename and run `svn cleanup`. (Btw. this should be the accepted answer.)

Comment: It caused later checksum mismatch on merging branch. So I had to checkout a copy and replace missing svn-base file. I started to checkout full project but cancelled when I got missing svn-base file.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, thank you. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The pristine files are a backup of the original file(that is missing). If you create a blank-file named as <file-guid.svn-base>, then cleanup will succeed but if will also copy your blank-file to the file that was missing. In my case the missing file was virus-infected therefore both the original file on my project directory and the backup .svn-base file inside the pristine directory was being removed and then Update/Commit/Cleanup used to give this error.

Answer (score 15):

I solved this by

1. Creating an empty file 
   /workingdirectory/.svn/pristine/da/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601800afd80009.svn-base
2. Run **svn cleanup**

Answer (score 8):

I got away by replacing the .svn directory with the same from a freshly checked-out copy. Fortunately for me, the local copy was on the same revision as the repo. Not sure what the implications would be if it was not the case.

Answer (score 3):

For me the file was there but had (1) appended to the name. (A copy)
ff4c7be3da460bb91144d6761cc5743536c983f4 (1).svn-base

I removed the "(1)" and cleanup ran fine
ff4c7be3da460bb91144d6761cc5743536c983f4.svn-base

Answer (score 1):

Took chunguiw's answer and wrote a Python (2.7) script for it, in case anyone's interested.

It follows the procedure: try a clean-up, parse output, touch missing file, repeat until done.

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import re

def touch(fname, times=None):
    with open(fname, 'a'):
        os.utime(fname, times)


svnbase_regex = re.compile(r"svn: E720002: Can't open file \'([^']+)\':")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Can pass SVN working copy's root folder as a parameter, otherwise runs on CWD
    try:
        root_folder = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        root_folder = "."
    root_folder = os.path.abspath(root_folder)
    os.chdir(root_folder)
    count = max_times = 10
    # Repeats file touching at most N times (the number above)
    while count > 0:
        count -= 1
        try:
            svn_output = subprocess.check_output("svn cleanup", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
            svn_output = e.output
        regex_match = svnbase_regex.search(svn_output)
        if not regex_match:
            break
        touch(regex_match.group(1))
        print "Done %s" % regex_match.group(1)
    print "Exited, fixed up %s missing entries." % (max_times - count)
    print "last SVN output:"
    print svn_output
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it too as a one-liner:

```
while [ 1 ] ; do OUTPUT=`svn cleanup 2>&1 | sed 's/^.* open file //' | sed 's/:.*$//' | sed "s/'//g"`;if [ "X${OUTPUT}" == "X" ] ; then   break; fi; echo $OUTPUT;touch $OUTPUT;done
```

Comment: Your "one-liner" is 180 characters long and contains 2 block statements. I'm not sure what is the definition of a one-liner in IT, but this surely ain't it. Just post it as a script, why are you obfuscating your answer?