# SVN- pristine text missing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, smartsvn

Already frustrated...Trying to update/commit/cleanup Tortoise SVN but always getting the notification about pristine text missing.

found some posts/questions on SO and on the web, nothing helped:

[pristine svn-base file missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243793/pristine-svn-base-file-missing/17800851) - suggests to clean pristine file, In my case it's the "pristine text" not found.

[pristine svn-base file missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243793/pristine-svn-base-file-missing) - suggests using smartSVN- clicking  "Modify"->validate Admin Area - which doesn't exist anymore in smart SVN I've just downloaded...

And 
[Error in Netbeans & Svn: Pristine text not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884030/error-in-netbeans-svn-pristine-text-not-found) 
doesn't have an answer...

Anybody- some help please?

Comment: That last question *does* have an answer, and the one I normally apply: if the working copy is damaged, just create a new one.

Comment: That's not an accepted answer, at least not for me. what about enabling future merge? what about logs? how can I compare different revisions if I loose all of that data?

Comment: No answer... Started merging into new checkout, 10 different branches, including changes... There must be a solution...

Comment: That's not how Subversion work. The working copy doesn't store the revision history—that belongs to the repository. Also, don't give accepted answers more credit than they deserve: some users don't care reporting back when they get their problem solved, some users accept wrong answers.

Comment: got it. Thanks. Actually I would accept, currently, after no other answer, you answer... can't accept comments... Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Subversion working copy format is not particularly robust and it's not strange that it gets corrupted now and then. When that happens, it's normally not worth the effort of fixing it. If `svn cleanup` can't cope with it, it's better to:

1. Check out a fresh working copy.
2. Copy your pending changes from the damaged working copy using your favourite file comparison tool ([Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), whatever).

You should not lose important information beyond changelists because everything else is stored on the repository, given that Subversion is a centralised version control system.

Comment: So mainly you say the last question I mentioned has an answer...Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have just had the same problem. The pristine text was actually there in

```
.svn/pristine/09/09verylongnamereportedbysvncleanup.svn-base
```

and by inspecting its contents I could track it down to

```
./local/foobar/somefile
```

One other way is to access directly the SVN database:

```
sqlite3 .svn/wc.db
sqlite> SELECT repos_path FROM nodes WHERE checksum LIKE '%7685df22%';
path/to/the/file/that/got/corrupted
sqlite> .quit
```

Remove the file (move it somewhere else, e.g. rename it to ".bak"), run a `svn cleanup`, a `svn update` on that file, and review apply any changes from the previously saved copy.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way for this. Take new SVN checkout for the same database/trunk.
After that go to corrupted_database/ find the .svn folder. rename this folder to .svn_old (use command  inside "corrupted_database" directory `mv corrupted_database/.svn corrupted_database/.svn_old`)

Now go to the "fresh_checkout" and find .svn folder. copy this folder to corrupted_database using command `cp -r fresh_checkout/.svn corrupted_database/`

Now do `cd corrupted_database; svn up` and check its working.